# How to install and use simpsons font?

Tags: fonts, installing

How to install and use the simpsons font?
I could not use the following command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{simpsons} 
\begin{document} 
\Bart 
\end{document}
```

I use TeXLive 2011.

Comment: You should give more detail: is your operating system Windows, Linux or Apple? There is some information [here](http://divisbyzero.com/2010/07/13/coffee-stains-and-the-simpsons-in-your-latex-document/)

Comment: I use Linux Ubuntu 11.04 + TeXLive 2011

Comment: It's in [texlive-extra](http://packages.debian.org/stable/tex/texlive-fonts-extra)

Comment: @DJP: It's not in TeX Live any more because of licensing issues. Since TeX Live/Debian is frozen to the October 2009 version, the font is still there.

Answer (score 15):

Get the style file and the tfm/mf one from CTAN, save the `simpsons.tfm` in `TEXMFHOME/fonts/tfm/public/simpsons/`, the *mf in the source part, then run texhash and it should work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpsons}

\begin{document} 
\Lisa
\Homer
\Bart
\Marge
\Maggie
\Burns
\SNPP

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Herbert i use TeXLive 2011 + Ubuntu. and I got the following error !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file simpsons): Font simpsons at 900 not found ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced! See my local file /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/simpsons how to execute texhash?

Comment: Did you installed the MetaFont source `simpsons.mf` with an additional `texhash`. Did `kpsewhich simpsons.mf` find the file?

Comment: @Regis: Please use comments for this form of feedback.

Comment: Herbert How is this done?

Comment: save the mf file into your home dir under `texmf/fonts/source/simpsons/` and the tf file under `texmf/fonts/tmf/public/simpsons/`, then it should work. However, did you tried to install the `texlive-extra` for Unbuntu?

Comment: I create /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/source/simpsons and mkdir /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/simpsons/, and i copy the files, and texhash mkdir /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/ but it did not work.

Comment: do you have texlive from tug.org installed or the Ubuntu version? And what does `kpsewhich simpsons.tfm` say?

Comment: @Herbert: i use TeXLive2011 manually installed from http://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html on '/usr/local/texlive/2011/'.

Comment: @Regis: ok, and what does `kpswhich` say?

Comment: I still can not solve this problem and not know what it means ``kpswhich``

Comment: sorry, it is `kpsewhich` which is a short program to search for TeX files. Run in a command window `kpsewhich simpsons.mf` and you'll get an output where the file is saved. If not then it isn't correct installed

Answer (score 1):

In Debian, I just noticed that the `texlive-fonts-extra` package no longer includes the Simpsons files, for copyright reasons. To make this work, I had to download the `.mf`, `.tfm`, and `.sty` files (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/usergrps/uktug/baskervi/4_4) and install thus:

```
/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/simpsons.sty

/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/source/simpsons/bart.mf
[put other mf files in same place]
  homer.mf     maggie.mf    simpsons.mf
burns.mf     lisa.mf      marge.mf     snpp.mf

/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/simpsons/simpsons.tfm
```

You can look in your `texmf.cnf` file  (look in `/usr/share` somewhere) to make sure `/usr/local/share/texmf` is `TEXMFLOCAL`:

```
TEXMFLOCAL = /usr/local/share/texmf
```

but I'm pretty sure it will be on most systems.

You can also install this in a home account, but I don't because I've got too many home accounts :)

Then run `texhash`. After that, examples work. Easiest one to test is `bart.tex` in the Simpsons folder.