# Trollface package

Tags: symbols, fun

Does anybody know if there is a package containing troll-faces similar to the [`simpsons` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/simpsons), where you just write the `\trollface` to insert a picture of a troll-face (e.g. `\Bart` for the `simpsons` package)?

Comment: Maybe there's no package, but depending of what you use it for you could write down your own macro.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How to install and use simpsons font?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28567/how-to-install-and-use-simpsons-font).

Comment: @PeterGrill No duplicate, he's not after the Simpsons font.

Comment: Can't you just use Comic Sans? `\end{opinion}` I don't think that there are fonts out there containing them. But you could easily [`\includegraphics`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) any graphic  (beware of copyright).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I could import it, but I was interested in finding out if there was actually a package out there for trollfaces :)

Comment: If you don't have it yet, [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/78/Trollface.svg) you have it in .svg, which you can convert into .pdf easily online.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Oppsss... I guess I need to learn to read... Perhaps I have been staring at LaTeX code for too long. :-)

Comment: Niels Sønderbæk

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have fun:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\trollface}{\resizebox{\fontcharht\font`X}{\fontcharwd\font`X}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.8pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (186.5230,42.6290) .. controls
  (181.3770,46.8210) and (177.2520,52.0360) .. (177.1840,61.3090) .. controls
  (173.4610,53.8470) and (177.9210,43.3950) .. (186.5230,42.6290) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (123.9480,53.8360) .. controls
  (131.6610,49.6690) and (133.9770,68.5560) .. (129.5520,73.4490) .. controls
  (130.1610,64.4350) and (129.6880,56.5020) .. (123.9480,53.8360) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (258.4390,84.6570) .. controls
  (251.9670,92.1160) and (243.0990,85.7280) .. (234.1560,84.6570) .. controls
  (214.8650,82.3460) and (196.3430,90.9360) .. (182.7880,96.7990) .. controls
  (152.3050,81.2930) and (190.8780,59.8650) .. (221.0810,61.3090) .. controls
  (241.5710,62.2870) and (255.3680,71.4410) .. (258.4390,84.6570) --
  cycle(206.1380,68.7800) .. controls (196.6960,73.9690) and (181.3370,73.2430)
  .. (180.9200,87.4590) .. controls (194.1550,88.2420) and (196.7990,78.4330) ..
  (209.8730,79.0540) .. controls (208.5950,75.6620) and (209.3090,70.2780) ..
  (206.1380,68.7800) -- cycle(249.1000,80.9220) .. controls (248.1190,76.6100)
  and (244.5910,74.8460) .. (238.8270,75.3180) .. controls (238.2690,81.1680)
  and (246.1370,78.5920) .. (249.1000,80.9220) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (135.1560,84.6570) .. controls
  (139.6320,83.6130) and (143.7260,82.0440) .. (147.2980,84.6570) .. controls
  (147.0140,91.5340) and (139.4010,91.0810) .. (135.1560,93.9970) .. controls
  (135.1560,99.9120) and (135.1560,105.8270) .. (135.1560,111.7420) .. controls
  (129.8970,116.4450) and (122.1800,118.6910) .. (118.3440,124.8180) .. controls
  (121.4790,132.8890) and (127.0330,138.5440) .. (134.2210,142.5630) .. controls
  (138.8510,142.3020) and (140.5480,137.0180) .. (145.4290,139.7610) .. controls
  (138.6120,162.3790) and (120.0140,140.4880) .. (112.7400,131.3550) .. controls
  (110.2100,132.5610) and (109.4200,135.5060) .. (105.2680,135.0910) .. controls
  (105.7160,132.1530) and (103.9380,131.4400) .. (103.4000,129.4870) .. controls
  (96.0960,131.2120) and (93.0790,137.2230) .. (83.7870,136.9590) .. controls
  (100.7200,129.2980) and (112.9440,116.9280) .. (127.6830,107.0720) .. controls
  (127.6830,102.7140) and (127.6830,98.3550) .. (127.6830,93.9970) .. controls
  (115.4770,85.0330) and (89.1830,90.1570) .. (75.3810,82.7890) .. controls
  (83.6980,60.8440) and (125.4950,70.6300) .. (135.1560,84.6570) --
  cycle(88.4580,79.0540) .. controls (93.0320,80.8510) and (100.4610,79.8720) ..
  (104.3350,78.1190) .. controls (99.7600,76.3220) and (92.3310,77.3020) ..
  (88.4580,79.0540) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (262.1750,78.1190) .. controls
  (266.1280,76.3740) and (271.8460,80.8820) .. (278.0530,79.9870) .. controls
  (278.0700,84.9570) and (269.8980,85.7630) .. (265.9110,83.7230) .. controls
  (266.0380,81.0470) and (272.3220,84.5300) .. (272.4490,81.8550) .. controls
  (269.2020,80.4330) and (264.6140,80.3510) .. (262.1750,78.1190) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (71.6460,81.8550) .. controls
  (48.4920,80.0360) and (22.9120,89.3230) .. (22.1460,111.7420) .. controls
  (22.0350,114.9910) and (22.2010,122.2410) .. (24.9480,126.6850) .. controls
  (29.3060,133.7360) and (40.2990,130.2490) .. (43.6270,139.7610) .. controls
  (26.4310,135.6320) and (18.5280,125.8960) .. (20.2780,108.9400) .. controls
  (22.7070,85.3990) and (45.7110,76.5680) .. (71.6460,81.8550) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (335.0240,98.6670) .. controls
  (328.5190,86.1820) and (314.4580,81.2520) .. (293.9290,82.7890) .. controls
  (309.8870,79.1500) and (332.2580,83.1200) .. (335.0240,98.6670) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (262.1750,87.4590) .. controls
  (263.4210,84.8030) and (266.3280,88.1800) .. (267.7790,88.3940) .. controls
  (266.4780,91.1060) and (263.1700,88.1290) .. (262.1750,87.4590) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (219.2130,88.3940) .. controls
  (228.9990,89.9850) and (233.5670,100.3980) .. (245.3640,101.4690) .. controls
  (259.7920,102.7790) and (267.3080,92.6370) .. (279.9210,89.3270) .. controls
  (314.2440,80.3190) and (342.0750,112.2860) .. (316.3460,139.7620) .. controls
  (312.1960,130.4970) and (320.4280,125.8410) .. (319.1480,114.5440) .. controls
  (317.6560,101.3880) and (305.0200,92.5910) .. (290.1950,94.9310) .. controls
  (285.2060,95.7190) and (280.8230,101.1010) .. (275.2520,103.3370) .. controls
  (255.1770,111.3950) and (219.5950,110.7840) .. (219.2130,88.3940) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (45.4950,90.2610) .. controls
  (42.3020,96.1040) and (28.5930,99.5050) .. (33.3530,116.4120) .. controls
  (28.6240,112.2490) and (33.6510,103.5000) .. (32.4190,96.7990) .. controls
  (36.9290,94.7710) and (41.1020,92.4060) .. (45.4950,90.2610) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (84.7220,108.0070) .. controls
  (88.8510,106.8440) and (89.8150,102.5150) .. (95.9300,103.3370) .. controls
  (99.8760,115.4730) and (84.1750,115.7950) .. (72.5810,115.4790) .. controls
  (71.5810,110.8750) and (69.6390,107.2120) .. (66.0430,105.2050) .. controls
  (55.3470,104.1610) and (49.0010,107.4650) .. (39.8920,108.0080) .. controls
  (44.8020,88.7320) and (76.0790,99.0260) .. (84.7220,108.0070) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (313.5430,127.6200) .. controls
  (308.5690,129.4390) and (304.6380,127.2380) .. (299.5340,126.6850) .. controls
  (296.2380,129.2760) and (293.4220,135.3040) .. (295.7980,140.6950) .. controls
  (283.8630,150.9330) and (275.9310,169.7570) .. (264.0430,182.7230) .. controls
  (234.6970,214.7360) and (183.6470,228.5980) .. (117.4100,225.6860) .. controls
  (95.9890,224.7450) and (71.0460,222.4130) .. (60.4380,211.6760) .. controls
  (43.6320,194.6670) and (42.8320,141.9400) .. (57.6360,121.0810) .. controls
  (59.0730,118.1590) and (57.2280,111.9560) .. (60.4380,110.8080) .. controls
  (67.8970,113.3780) and (63.8270,124.2490) .. (66.0420,130.4210) .. controls
  (70.6570,143.2850) and (96.3870,151.5800) .. (114.6080,153.7710) .. controls
  (182.9370,161.9820) and (240.6520,126.1850) .. (285.5240,110.8080) .. controls
  (286.8670,107.4810) and (286.4780,102.4220) .. (289.2600,100.5350) .. controls
  (294.8400,102.4830) and (292.5530,107.1600) .. (294.8640,110.8080) .. controls
  (299.9820,118.8930) and (312.2430,119.4850) .. (313.5430,127.6200) --
  cycle(256.5710,133.2240) .. controls (256.5710,137.8940) and
  (256.5710,142.5640) .. (256.5710,147.2340) .. controls (274.1010,144.2160) and
  (289.2540,138.8220) .. (290.1940,119.2140) .. controls (274.7910,119.6880) and
  (268.9450,129.7200) .. (256.5710,133.2240) -- cycle(57.6360,143.4970) ..
  controls (59.9280,143.2360) and (61.9410,137.9240) .. (60.4380,136.9590) ..
  controls (59.6630,139.2970) and (57.8790,140.6280) .. (57.6360,143.4970) --
  cycle(205.2030,149.1020) .. controls (205.1680,155.3640) and
  (207.5990,159.1590) .. (208.0050,164.9790) .. controls (223.7610,158.0080) and
  (247.7210,159.2420) .. (249.1000,137.8940) .. controls (235.1800,138.6090) and
  (220.1700,146.3200) .. (205.2030,149.1020) -- cycle(66.9760,166.8470) ..
  controls (67.8590,159.9310) and (72.0280,150.7120) .. (67.9100,144.4320) ..
  controls (64.8520,149.0080) and (57.2650,163.7120) .. (66.9760,166.8470) --
  cycle(257.5050,174.3180) .. controls (259.8780,172.3290) and
  (263.2370,170.8490) .. (265.9110,167.7800) .. controls (269.5100,163.6490) and
  (276.6900,150.9880) .. (275.2510,150.9680) .. controls (264.4210,152.7880) and
  (248.8670,162.0370) .. (257.5050,174.3180) -- cycle(77.2500,170.5820) ..
  controls (81.8400,169.1510) and (85.3880,173.5910) .. (87.5240,171.5170) ..
  controls (84.1720,165.9570) and (90.7970,162.3580) .. (90.3260,156.5740) ..
  controls (84.8320,156.4640) and (82.4630,153.2290) .. (78.1840,151.9040) ..
  controls (73.1060,155.9740) and (76.7130,164.2210) .. (77.2500,170.5820) --
  cycle(195.8630,152.8370) .. controls (184.6230,155.6070) and
  (172.2560,157.2490) .. (161.3060,160.3090) .. controls (161.3060,164.9790) and
  (161.3060,169.6490) .. (161.3060,174.3190) .. controls (177.4140,175.4840) and
  (188.1850,171.3110) .. (200.5330,168.7150) .. controls (199.4780,162.9210) and
  (199.4950,156.0550) .. (195.8630,152.8370) -- cycle(94.0610,171.5170) ..
  controls (102.0880,173.7640) and (111.3050,174.8210) .. (122.0800,174.3190) ..
  controls (121.4640,169.8440) and (123.0400,164.0500) .. (122.0800,162.1770) ..
  controls (113.6500,161.2670) and (103.9510,161.6260) .. (97.7970,158.4420) ..
  controls (96.5510,162.7990) and (96.3510,168.2020) .. (94.0610,171.5170) --
  cycle(131.4200,162.1770) .. controls (131.6440,167.0710) and
  (129.1470,169.2430) .. (128.6180,173.3850) .. controls (135.5560,175.4760) and
  (146.2990,173.7610) .. (154.7690,174.3190) .. controls (154.7690,169.6490) and
  (154.7690,164.9790) .. (154.7690,160.3090) .. controls (145.9280,159.8740) and
  (140.7430,163.0940) .. (131.4200,162.1770) -- cycle(211.7410,178.0550) ..
  controls (210.4210,189.9590) and (217.7640,193.2010) .. (219.2130,202.3380) ..
  controls (232.4160,197.1720) and (241.9620,188.3510) .. (252.8360,180.8570) ..
  controls (247.5230,178.3850) and (247.9630,170.1630) .. (246.2980,164.0450) ..
  controls (236.3020,170.2380) and (224.6830,174.8070) .. (211.7410,178.0550) --
  cycle(168.7780,190.1960) .. controls (168.0510,199.3280) and
  (170.0950,205.6890) .. (169.7120,214.4780) .. controls (187.7230,215.6780) and
  (199.0090,210.1530) .. (211.7410,206.0730) .. controls (209.4850,196.8090) and
  (203.6060,191.1700) .. (203.3350,179.9220) .. controls (193.1930,184.7240) and
  (182.5080,188.9810) .. (168.7780,190.1960) -- cycle(66.0420,203.2710) ..
  controls (65.9030,195.9380) and (62.2210,192.1490) .. (58.5700,188.3280) ..
  controls (60.1730,194.1960) and (62.3150,199.5260) .. (66.0420,203.2710) --
  cycle(83.7880,211.6770) .. controls (81.6570,203.8460) and (79.4550,196.0850)
  .. (72.5800,192.9980) .. controls (72.0370,198.2100) and (75.3710,199.5460) ..
  (75.3820,204.2050) .. controls (74.8020,207.4170) and (70.3580,206.0980) ..
  (69.7780,207.0070) .. controls (73.0720,209.9390) and (78.5480,210.6890) ..
  (83.7880,211.6770) -- cycle(133.2880,195.8000) .. controls (133.3440,203.8380)
  and (136.3930,208.8840) .. (136.0900,217.2810) .. controls (144.8000,216.9630)
  and (154.9630,218.0960) .. (162.2410,216.3460) .. controls (161.9570,212.0840)
  and (160.6930,201.2210) .. (161.3070,192.9970) .. controls (152.8320,194.8520)
  and (141.9890,197.0030) .. (133.2880,195.8000) -- cycle(92.1930,212.6110) ..
  controls (95.7960,213.9890) and (99.2500,215.5160) .. (104.3350,215.4130) ..
  controls (103.0850,209.1910) and (98.9260,205.8780) .. (98.7310,198.6010) ..
  controls (93.8100,198.5410) and (91.8760,195.4940) .. (86.5890,195.7990) ..
  controls (87.4560,202.1920) and (94.9240,205.5740) .. (92.1930,212.6110) --
  cycle(106.2030,197.6680) .. controls (107.8940,204.6930) and
  (112.1030,209.2020) .. (113.6750,216.3470) .. controls (118.0900,216.6280) and
  (125.5740,218.7360) .. (129.5520,216.3470) .. controls (128.6800,203.5710) and
  (121.5510,192.9510) .. (106.2030,197.6680) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (197.7310,121.0820) .. controls
  (198.7120,132.7370) and (196.2330,144.5570) .. (184.6560,140.6950) .. controls
  (183.4110,132.5700) and (193.0760,132.9910) .. (191.1930,126.6850) .. controls
  (189.4350,120.7980) and (181.5510,124.0340) .. (174.3820,121.0810) .. controls
  (176.0420,109.8510) and (193.8450,115.8040) .. (197.7310,121.0820) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (200.5330,115.4790) .. controls
  (204.4700,115.3180) and (201.1740,117.5700) .. (200.5330,118.2810) .. controls
  (203.9060,128.7760) and (224.3770,116.4100) .. (228.5530,125.7530) .. controls
  (220.2110,119.9870) and (196.2170,130.8070) .. (200.5330,115.4790) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (31.4850,117.3460) .. controls
  (35.1880,120.4920) and (37.8990,124.6310) .. (42.6930,126.6860) .. controls
  (37.0450,129.1980) and (31.9330,123.1410) .. (31.4850,117.3460) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (180.9200,129.4870) .. controls
  (180.7300,132.4100) and (181.5500,136.3430) .. (179.9860,137.8930) .. controls
  (174.0290,133.1600) and (163.2140,138.0600) .. (154.7690,135.0910) .. controls
  (155.7830,124.9850) and (172.8760,127.2090) .. (180.9200,129.4870) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (258.4390,207.0070) .. controls
  (259.6460,209.1990) and (251.8250,210.0340) .. (248.1660,211.6770) .. controls
  (221.0230,223.8620) and (191.6300,245.8770) .. (151.0330,242.4980) .. controls
  (197.2180,241.0510) and (221.2870,217.4870) .. (258.4390,207.0070) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (65.1080,225.6870) .. controls
  (74.4620,238.4370) and (92.9790,242.0240) .. (113.6740,243.4320) .. controls
  (93.8120,244.9240) and (68.5880,243.6900) .. (65.1080,225.6870) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (161.3070,232.2250) .. controls
  (147.9730,232.8420) and (127.4930,235.8070) .. (112.7410,233.1590) .. controls
  (113.5640,233.3060) and (107.4200,234.1800) .. (110.8730,232.2250) .. controls
  (128.2930,233.0280) and (146.3320,230.9210) .. (161.3070,232.2250) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (127.6840,243.4320) .. controls
  (131.1270,241.2720) and (138.5660,243.1070) .. (143.5610,242.4980) .. controls
  (140.1180,244.6580) and (132.6790,242.8230) .. (127.6840,243.4320) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (38.0230,42.6290) .. controls (82.5390,0.2510)
  and (168.4500,6.1510) .. (250.9680,7.1380) .. controls (258.8160,7.2320) and
  (267.6870,5.7700) .. (274.3170,7.1380) .. controls (286.1880,9.5890) and
  (299.5410,24.1610) .. (306.0720,35.1580) .. controls (310.9170,43.3120) and
  (313.1390,55.1730) .. (317.2800,62.2430) .. controls (330.3650,84.5890) and
  (363.7570,90.1510) .. (354.6380,129.4880) .. controls (350.3990,147.7790) and
  (330.9450,155.1810) .. (321.0150,173.3850) .. controls (317.4380,179.9440) and
  (316.7720,187.3410) .. (313.5430,192.9980) .. controls (301.1180,214.7730) and
  (268.7750,231.0160) .. (241.6280,243.4320) .. controls (220.9940,252.8700) and
  (198.3130,267.1020) .. (179.0520,272.3850) .. controls (166.3570,275.8670) and
  (147.5010,278.7970) .. (128.6170,282.6580) .. controls (101.5110,288.2020) and
  (70.6950,290.9440) .. (49.2300,281.7240) .. controls (38.0840,276.9370) and
  (25.4570,265.4370) .. (23.0790,254.6390) .. controls (17.5010,229.3100) and
  (34.1810,186.6860) .. (26.8150,156.5730) .. controls (21.7590,135.9030) and
  (3.9090,121.6480) .. (10.0030,95.8650) .. controls (15.1720,74.0010) and
  (40.4630,75.0640) .. (38.0230,42.6290) -- cycle(346.2320,130.4220) .. controls
  (356.6420,101.6040) and (332.1320,76.8320) .. (298.5990,78.1190) .. controls
  (304.7890,76.0110) and (311.4390,78.0850) .. (318.2120,78.1190) .. controls
  (301.9840,58.2020) and (298.0540,17.1590) .. (264.0420,13.6760) .. controls
  (216.9920,8.8570) and (155.8050,15.1380) .. (110.8720,19.2800) .. controls
  (142.1830,27.4840) and (175.9850,13.4080) .. (208.9390,16.4780) .. controls
  (239.3500,19.3120) and (260.6870,37.8100) .. (277.1190,51.9690) .. controls
  (257.8750,41.2170) and (237.7900,21.1210) .. (208.0050,18.3460) .. controls
  (183.2390,16.0380) and (165.7270,22.7740) .. (144.4950,23.9500) .. controls
  (127.4810,24.8920) and (109.8000,20.5540) .. (94.9950,22.0820) .. controls
  (77.6030,23.8780) and (47.9860,38.7270) .. (43.6270,51.9700) .. controls
  (42.0390,56.7930) and (43.7690,62.7160) .. (41.7590,67.8470) .. controls
  (34.6190,86.0780) and (9.3930,91.1260) .. (18.4100,122.0170) .. controls
  (20.9200,130.6170) and (27.7020,135.5720) .. (30.5520,141.6310) .. controls
  (38.9450,159.4780) and (35.5640,188.2320) .. (33.3540,209.8110) .. controls
  (31.9730,223.2950) and (27.9960,238.8790) .. (30.5520,251.8390) .. controls
  (37.3950,286.5250) and (104.0000,281.3020) .. (136.0910,273.3200) .. controls
  (147.5600,270.4660) and (157.6800,265.1130) .. (166.9120,263.9800) .. controls
  (170.9690,263.4820) and (175.3540,265.1670) .. (181.8560,263.9800) .. controls
  (191.0090,262.3080) and (203.8080,252.5830) .. (214.5440,247.1680) .. controls
  (246.4100,231.0990) and (289.5540,216.8260) .. (307.0070,189.2620) .. controls
  (311.4680,182.2160) and (313.1470,170.7890) .. (316.3470,164.9790) .. controls
  (318.5940,160.8990) and (324.7580,160.0830) .. (323.8190,154.7060) .. controls
  (324.2180,156.2110) and (320.3370,157.8400) .. (320.0830,155.6400) .. controls
  (331.4360,150.5690) and (342.5940,140.4950) .. (346.2320,130.4220) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (77.2500,36.0910) .. controls
  (84.6910,22.9450) and (107.2240,33.1150) .. (124.8820,33.2890) .. controls
  (150.9490,33.5470) and (176.6190,25.1470) .. (200.5330,26.7510) .. controls
  (229.3460,28.6840) and (255.4970,42.3890) .. (269.6470,59.4400) .. controls
  (251.0790,44.9400) and (224.3560,28.4240) .. (188.3910,28.6190) .. controls
  (169.3380,28.7230) and (149.8110,36.2530) .. (124.8810,35.1570) .. controls
  (106.1230,34.3320) and (89.2790,27.8450) .. (77.2500,36.0910) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (182.7880,39.8270) .. controls
  (180.4770,39.9450) and (181.2000,38.6830) .. (182.7880,38.8920) .. controls
  (214.8340,36.0440) and (246.6730,40.8290) .. (257.5050,62.2420) .. controls
  (243.3820,43.9870) and (216.2760,38.7170) .. (182.7880,39.8270) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (134.2220,48.2320) .. controls
  (116.5830,42.4210) and (80.0680,39.9560) .. (74.4480,61.3080) .. controls
  (71.7860,48.3020) and (92.6910,40.9070) .. (112.7400,41.6940) .. controls
  (120.7850,42.0110) and (131.5240,42.7730) .. (134.2220,48.2320) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (315.4110,148.1670) .. controls
  (334.4690,145.0120) and (338.3490,122.0640) .. (335.0240,99.6010) .. controls
  (340.8540,112.7940) and (335.5300,126.2080) .. (334.0900,139.7620) .. controls
  (328.2670,142.9670) and (324.5500,148.2770) .. (315.4110,148.1670) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (47.3630,228.4880) .. controls
  (49.4920,229.7830) and (47.7110,234.9890) .. (48.2970,237.8280) .. controls
  (83.8900,267.4720) and (165.4050,250.6590) .. (207.0710,236.8940) .. controls
  (232.9420,228.3470) and (255.0540,213.7040) .. (278.9860,207.0060) .. controls
  (240.0480,233.7560) and (154.7340,260.6540) .. (83.7870,255.5720) .. controls
  (67.1820,254.3840) and (43.7210,247.9240) .. (47.3630,228.4880) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}

\tiny Hello world! \trollface

\scriptsize Hello world! \trollface

\footnotesize Hello world! \trollface

\small Hello world! \trollface

\normalsize Hello world! \trollface

\large Hello world! \trollface

\Large Hello world! \trollface

\LARGE Hello world! \trollface

\huge Hello world! \trollface

\Huge Hello world! \trollface

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Troll]

Voilà! `:)`

<sub>For more info, [this question](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) might help. `:)`</sub>

Comment: Certainly the question is constructive :P Anyway, how have you generated the code?

Comment: @Manuel: There's a plugin for Inkscape that exports the drawing to a (not optimized, very verbose) TikZ code, called `inkscape2tikz`. `:)`

Comment: Okey. I knew about it, but I wondered if there were another option. Thanks.

Comment: I am really trolled by `For more info...` `:-(`

Comment: @HarishKumar Don't spoil it! (Delete your comment?)

Comment: @Paulo: Only you ... `:D`

Comment: The question linked after „For more info“ helped me a lot today :)

Comment: @Harish: ♥ `:)`

Comment: There's not enough upvote arrows for this answer!

Comment: I see a `trollduck` package on the horizon :-)

Comment: @Daniel: Possibly. `:)`