# How to install the simpsons package on MacOSX?

Tags: mac, texshop, installing-fonts

I am trying to use the simpsons package. The texeditor I use is TeXShop. I am not sure which TeXLive version I am using. When I go to `/usr/local/`, I find three different versions; `2013, 2014 and texmf-local`. I use MacOSX. Previously, when I was doing something I froze the TeXLive version that was installed or I may have created `texmf-local`. I am not sure how to install the simpsons package?

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28567/how-to-install-and-use-simpsons-font) is very similar to my problem. I am not able to get anywhere with it though.

Comment: (1) Your TeX distribution is ancient.  Install [MacTeX 2017](https://www.tug.org/mactex/)!  (2) Due to licensing issues the [`simpsons`](https://ctan.org/pkg/simpsons) package is not shipped with MacTeX and has to be installed manually.

Comment: I tried to very unsuccessfully install the simpsons package manually. If I upgrade the TeX distribution does it overwrite the one I am using at the moment?

Comment: @Mischief_Monkey no, you can choose: http://www.tug.org/mactex/multipletexdistributions.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a mac you have to first create the `texmf`-tree under `~/Library`  (Alan Munn has a nice little script for that: https://www.msu.edu/~amunn/latex/make-local-texmf.zip).

Then you have to create the following directories:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/Library/texmf/fonts/source/simpsons/
$ mkdir -p ~/Library/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/simpsons/
```

After that, you have to copy the files accordingly:

```
$ cp simpsons.sty ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/
$ cp simpsons.tfm ~/Library/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/simpsons/
$ cp *.mf ~/Library/texmf/fonts/source/simpsons
```

Comment: Thanks @DG', I might have previously used Alun Munn's script, because I already had a very similar directory structure as you have provided here. Trouble is I cant remember the steps I had followed. But all good, it works :). I was failing to get it to work previously, because I created a folder called simpsons in the fonts subdirectory. I didn't know we had to place the .sty, .tfm and *.mf files in separate subdirectories. Your solution is perfect.