# Making symbols from *Science made Stupid*

Tags: math-mode, symbols, fun

There is a funny, award-winning book [*Science made Stupid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Made_Stupid) that parodies gradeschool textbooks. In this book, there is the following table of symbols used in mathematics.

[image: Amusing symbols used in mathematics]

These symbols are each made of typical symbols available in tex. But I was wondering how one might go about making these available (in math mode) in latex? I'm particularly interested in the first four — but I suspect that once any of them are made, all can be made with a bit of twiddling.

It's probably possible to create the symbol in tikz, but I don't think this works well in math mode (e.g. what if I want to put "is very reminiscent of" as a subscript?). I have similar qualms about using kludge formed with `rotatebox` in `graphicx`. I suspect there are better ways.

Comment: It can be done.  Yjere is always metafont.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28567/how-to-install-and-use-simpsons-font?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C64.6642

Comment: If you want to put it as a subscript, you can define your TikZ symbol using `\mathchoice`.

Comment: You might find either ⋚ (less than, greater than or equal to) or ⋛ (greater than, less than or equal to) an adequate stand-in for “greater than, less than, or possibly equal to.”Also ⪋ or ⪌. Or maybe ⪑ or ⪒ .

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different techniques used here.

1. For the "perhaps equal to" symbol, the symbol is drawn using Ti*k*Z and scaled to the height of a `\cong` symbol using `\scalerel*` from the `scalerel` package. Since `\cong` changes size in scripts, the new symbol does also.
2. For the "has some kind of relation to" symbol, `\mathpalette` is used together with `\rotatebox` to rotate a `?` symbol. Note: `\rotatebox` requires the `graphicx` package, which is loaded by `scalerel`.
3. For the "reminiscent" symbol, `\mathpalette` is again used, together with `\ooalign` to superimpose an `=` with a `\wr` symbol (the vertical `\sim`).
4. Finally, for the "probably has nothing to do with" symbol, `\mathchoice` is used since there are minor spacing adjustments needed for each style.

[image]

More details can be found in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/125871) and its answers.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, scalerel}

\newcommand{\perhaps}{\mathrel{\scalerel*{\tikz{
    \useasboundingbox (0,-.2) rectangle (1,.6);
    \draw[line width=1.4pt, line cap=round, line join=round](0,-.04)--(1,-.04)(0,.2)--(.4,.2)--(0,.5)(1,.2)--(.6,.2)--(1,.5);
}}{\cong}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\somekind}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\some@kind\relax}}
\newcommand{\some@kind}[2]{%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\m@th#1?$}
}

\newcommand{\reminiscent}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\reminisc@nt\relax}}
\newcommand{\reminisc@nt}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1=$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\wr$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\probnothing}{\mathrel{\mathchoice
  {\ooalign{\rotatebox{90}{?}\cr\raisebox{1.7ex}{\rotatebox{-90}{?}}\cr}}
  {\ooalign{\rotatebox{90}{?}\cr\raisebox{1.7ex}{\rotatebox{-90}{?}}\cr}}
  {\ooalign{\raisebox{-.1ex}{\rotatebox{90}{$\scriptstyle ?$}}\cr\raisebox{1.25ex}{\rotatebox{-90}{$\scriptstyle ?$}}\cr}}
  {\ooalign{\raisebox{-.1ex}{\rotatebox{90}{$\scriptscriptstyle ?$}}\cr\raisebox{1ex}{\rotatebox{-90}{$\scriptscriptstyle ?$}}\cr}}
}}

\begin{document}

$A\perhaps B_{A\perhaps B_{A\perhaps B}}$

$A\somekind B_{A\somekind B_{A\somekind B}}$

$A\reminiscent B_{A\reminiscent B_{A\reminiscent B}}$

$A\probnothing B_{A\probnothing B_{A\probnothing B}}$

\end{document}
```